# Was the Eye of Providence also a symbol of Bavarian illuminati?

Tags: political-history, religious-history

If no, then where did it come from?

[This site (How the secret Illuminati society really did start in Germany)](https://www.thelocal.de/20170509/how-the-secret-illuminati-society-really-did-start-in-germany) claims that the owl of Minerva was the symbol of the Bavarian Illuminati.

I did my research but I think the symbol of the Bavarian illuminati was an owl, not the [Eye of Providence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence)

Comment: Just saying "I did my research" forces us to repeat all of your research. What sources did you consult? Where did you look? What did you find? What lead you to this hypothesis? What supports the notion that the Eye of Providence was a symbol of the Bavarian Illuminati?  What leads you to believe that the Bavarian Illuminati had a symbol at all?  The first sentence of the quoted Wikipedia page gives the origin for the Eye of Providence, which very probably predates the Bavarian Illuminati - why is that insufficient?

Comment: Its Sauron of course ;-)

Comment: Please clarify: Is the origin/history of the symbol your aim or that of the group? Do you read 'your sources' (please disclose what these are, cite/quote from them) as saying the group 'had' one symbol, and only one symbol but not the other?

Answer (score 4):

> There's a strong argument that the floating eye on the dollar, the Eye of Providence above a pyramid, comes from Freemasonry. (There's also an argument that it was meant as a Christian symbol; the only thing we know for certain is that it has nothing to do with the Bavarian Illuminati.) [*Vox*](https://www.vox.com/2015/5/19/8624675/what-is-the-real-illuminati)

Other sources: a [random conspiracy site](http://consciousreporter.com/conspiracy-against-consciousness/corruption-sacred-symbols-all-seeing-eye-part-2/); a [second random conspiracy](http://www.blackdiamondsocialclub.com/single-post/2017/04/07/Symbols-of-the-Illuminati-All-Seeing-Eye) site. [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whose-eye-is-on-the-Illuminati-logo).

None of those sources look particularly credible to me; I didn't spot citations or research, just assertions.  At least to me the answer to your question "Was the Eye of Providence a symbol of the Bavarian Illuminati?" Is "no, there is no evidence to support that".  I choose not to closely examine the assertions they make  - for example the link between the Eye of Providence and the Eye of Re, because that isn't germane to your question, and because I don't place a great deal of credibility in the sites mentioned.

I'm choosing to interpret this question as a request for information about historical imagery, and not as a question about conspiracy theories - because those are explicitly out of scope for this site.

Comment: Eye of Re *looks* very different. Take this example https://www.florence.net/painting-cena-in-emmaus-uffizi-gallery.aspx inspired by – well those depucted – plus Proverbs 15:3. That doesn't preclude it was chosen because of FM, but at least that it wasn't invented then by short-lived Bavarian clubs.

Comment: Two of your links trace back the symbolism to Egypt. While the symbol is *old* (duh, it's an eye) the meaning is shifted and the design quite distinct from older ones. // Not sure why you include "refutation" at all. I do not read "where did it come from" as "Am I right: Martha Washington was a member and insisted…?" But perhaps just the more benign, but still in need of clarification: "two different claims of symbols used/connected to Bavarian club, which is it, did they invent the EoP?" // The much older painting stears at least the 'who invented it' away from the club in any form